# Data Binding: multiple sources for one property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

I want to bind one property to multiple sources. My reason for this are things like this:

```
midpoint=point2.X - point1.X; //depends on two sources!
```

How could this be realised? As far as I know it's not directly possible out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is a [`MultiBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx).

From the MSDN documentation:

```
<TextBlock Name="textBox2" DataContext="{StaticResource NameListData}">
  <TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myNameConverter}"
                  ConverterParameter="FormatLastFirst">
      <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
      <Binding Path="LastName"/>
    </MultiBinding>
  </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: thank you very much, exactly what i was looking for. i obviously used the wrong search terms.